# How to export/import all Moodle configuration?

Tags: php, configuration, moodle

Well, thats the question: **Is there a way to export/import all moodle configuration?**

I found this: https://docs.moodle.org/dev/XML_Administrator_Settings
But it seems that they have not implemented it yet.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to import/export all Moodle configuration directly from Moodle GUI.

But, because all Moodle configuration are saved in database tables, backing up and restoring Moodle database can do the trick.

Here are some steps and commands (for Ubuntu platform):

**Step 1:** Backup Moodle DB:

```
$mysqldump -u<username> -p<password> <db_name_to_dump> path/fileName.sql
```

e.g

```
$mysqldump -u root -p root moodle /documents/moodleDbDump.sql
```

**Step 2:** Copy `Moodledata` folder.

**Step 3:** Create database on target machine.

**Step 4:** Restore backup db on target machine:

```
$mysql -u<username> -p<password> <db_name_to_restore> < backup_fileName.sql
```

e.g.

```
$mysql -u root -p root moodle < moodleDbDump.sql
```

Comment: I'm upgrading to a Moodle 2.9. But many of configs are still the same after upgrading. But i can't restore the database of a older version of moodle. Sorry for not adding this information.

Comment: When you say "many of the configs are still same after upgrading" it means you are getting desired result else without successful export/import of all Moodle configuration how happen all your configs are still same after upgrading.

Comment: Sorry, i'm not a native english. What I mean was: the avalaible configs are the same after upgrade. Don't change between versions.